# how to delete rows from sqlite by comparing date

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to create a delete function in my app to delete the rows added more than a day ago and a column whose has a value 'C'. I'm having problem how to compare the current system date with date stored in the database column,

```
public int RemoveSyncData(){

  DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
  Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();
  String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calObj.getTime());
  Log.e("current date",currentDate);

  int totalRows = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE,SYN_STATUS + "= ? and " + CREATED_DATE + " < " + currentDate, new String[] {"C,"});

  db.close();
  return totalRows;
}
```

I'm using the same date format for comparing, bleow is my Logcat

```
07-24 10:50:37.018: E/AndroidRuntime(21580): Caused by:   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "10": syntax error (code 1): ,    while compiling: DELETE FROM dailyattendance WHERE sync_status= ? and   created_date < 07-24-2015 10:50:36 AM
07-24 10:50:37.018: E/AndroidRuntime(21580):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-24 10:50:37.018: E/AndroidRuntime(21580):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
07-24 10:50:37.018: E/AndroidRuntime(21580):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
07-24 10:50:37.018: E/AndroidRuntime(21580):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
```

Comment: Put single quote around `CREATED_DATE` - like `and '" + CREATED_DATE + "' <`

Comment: SQL syntax error is shown in your exception.  Single quotes are needed to fix SQL syntax error

Comment: can u show me in full line.

Comment: My comment was not entirely correct.  I have posted an answer.  Have not tested it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction in code like below should help.  We need to use single quotes to enclose values

```
int totalRows = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE, SYN_STATUS + "= ? and " + CREATED_DATE + " < '" + currentDate + "'", new String[] {"C"});
```

Also, you could use DATE_TIME function of SQLite to convert string to date time for matching purposes.  Here is one way you can re-write your code.  Note the changes to `SimpleDateFormat` format, and change to query.

```
public int RemoveSyncData(){

  DBHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();
  String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calObj.getTime());
  Log.e("current date",currentDate);

  int totalRows = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE,SYN_STATUS + "= ? and " + CREATED_DATE + " < DATE_TIME(?)", new String[] {"C", currentDate});

  db.close();
  return totalRows;
}
```

I have not tested this above code, but it should give the idea.

Comment: Thanks Wand, it helped :)

Comment: if i ask you a problem, would you answer that?

Comment: Ask in forum.  If I know answer will reply, else someelse will

Comment: on executing above code i get an error that no such function DATE_TIME. can u suggest any solution.